# Is there an existing OAI-PMH data provider package

Tags: oai

I have been asked to come up with a OAI-PMH data provider (as opposed to a service provider/harvester). This should expose a small postgresql database with research metadata.

My question is: Should I develop this from scratch, or is there something I can use? I can find plenty of service providers/harvesters, but I don't see any data providers (i.e. the things which the harvester sends requests to)

Many thanks,

Michel